# Grafana loki higher data is not getting displayed on my loki dashboard above 200mb logs

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

i have installed the grafana in my local server where i can  get my logs.
i have installed loki and promtail to get my logs on dashboard , but the problem which i'm getting is that it is showing me max queries exceeds 5000, is there any solution where i can increse the size and change it.

```
[response larger than the max message size (193605955 vs 104857600)
{filename="/var/sss/storing/logs/centralize_o_request_response_log_2024-01-6.log"} |= ``
too many outstanding requests

max entries limit per query exceeded, limit > max_entries_limit (100000 > 5000)]
```

above is my problem statement
how can i solve this issue?

i am trying this on `ubuntu 22`, not using docker
My configuration of `loki.yaml`

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: tsdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v12
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
```

i tried to change the configuration in `loki-local-config.yaml` as entering the max_query_size=10000, and this as well

```
storage_config:
  ...
  limit_configs:
    - name: "loki_logs_per_stream"
      type: logs
      enforce_within_query_window: true
      period: 168h
      limit: 5000000
    - name: "loki_series"
      type: series
      enforce_within_query_window: false
      period: 0
      limit: 2000000
```

but still i have not got the success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follow

```yaml
limits_config:
  # Maximum number of log entries that will be returned for a query. default = 5000
  max_entries_limit_per_query: 10000
```